# SoundManager 32-sound ceiling hit error

Tags: soundmanager2

When playing the same long sounds in a 100 interval, after few seconds I start getting a “No sound hardware, or 32-sound ceiling hit” error.

To repro this issue:

1-  Open a browser (I used IE10 and Chrome)

2-  Launch its developer tool (F12) and go to the Console Tab.

3-  Make sure the volume is low as a sound will start playing as soon as you hit the following link.

4-  Hit this URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0B92G3ib2ozRVcS1RcHI5eGpzOXc/default.htm

5-  Sound will start playing and then there will be a silence. During the silence you will be getting the error “test: play(): No sound hardware, or 32-sound ceiling hit” in the console. (SoundManager is in debugging mode so you will get a lot of logged messages before)

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 32 simultaneous sounds. If you are playing a new sound every 100ms, you will hit that limit in 3.2 seconds. That's what the 32-sound ceiling means.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this around by checking if the sound playState is == 0 before playing the same sound and setting its position to 0 if playState is != 0.

Code looks like this:

```
if (this.sounds[id].playState == 0) { 
    this.sounds[id].play({ volume: this.volume * 100.0 }); 
} else { 
    // if sound is already playing then move it to the beginning  
    this.sounds[id].setPosition(0); 
}
```

Sound feels a little choppy though. If there is a better way to fix this, please let me know.